# Pegar Id e passar para outra função no click botão

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Galera,

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma tabela e a cada registro tenho um link.

Ao clicar nesse link eu pego o ID da seguinte forma e chamo um modal.

```
<script>
 $(document).on("click", "a", function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("clique")) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#md-default').modal('show');
    }
 });
</script>
```

Nesse modal eu tenho um botão de confirmação, como posso pegar o id que cliquei no link?
Existe como declarar uma variável global e nela armazenar o valor o ID e depois recuperar pelo clique do outro botão?

```
<script>
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
alert("Como pegar o ID alterior??");

}
</script>
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar esse valor em um input hidden por exemplo?
Esse botão é um input ou um link? Não pode passar o parametro por GET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você optar por adicionar ao escopo global poderia fazer algo como:

```
<script>
 var idSel;
 $(document).on("click", "a", function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("clique")) {
        idSel = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#md-default').modal('show');
    }
 });

 $('#submitButton').click(function() {
    console.log(idSel);
 });
</script>
```

```js
 var idSel;
 $(document).on("click", "a", function(){
    idSel = $(this).attr('id');
 });

 $('#submitButton').click(function() {
    console.log(idSel);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link">Clique em mim</a>
<br/><br/>
<button id="submitButton" >Ok</button>
```

Comment: Tem razão Lucas, vou fazer conforme sua dica. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro passares o ID para um campo data- do elemento que faz o submit.

Assim evitas variáveis globais e o botão que confirma tem a informação que deve ter. Repara também no ajuste da classe `clique`, que dispensa assim um `if` desnecessário.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.clique", function(){
    $('#submitButton').data('id', this.id);
    $('#md-default').modal('show');
});
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    alert(id);
});
```